# Subscribing to Azure Push Notification service in Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I tried to integrate with Push Notifications to my forms application. Azure messaging component is used for achieving this. 
Below is the code i am using. I am getting the trigger to `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications` method. But `RegisterNativeAsync` method doesn't seem to be doing the job.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
{
var push = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
new NSSet());
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(push);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
}
else
{
const UIRemoteNotificationType not = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound;
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(not);
}
}

public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{

        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(conStirng, NotifHubPath);
        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) =>
        {
            //Get device token
            var id = deviceToken.ToString();
            var tag = "username";
            var tags = new List<string> { tag };
            Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(id, new NSSet(tags.ToArray()), (errorCallback) =>
            {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                {
                    //Log to output
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here? How can i confirm if the Register function is success or failure.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the error from the response of the register method is null or not.  if it is null means the it is a success.

```
var hub = new SBNotificationHub (cs, "your-hub-name");
    hub.RegisterNativeAsync (deviceToken, null, err => {
        if (err != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.Description);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
    });
```

In the case of windows universal apps we can check the registrationId property of the response.

```
private async void InitNotificationsAsync()
{
    var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

    var hub = new NotificationHub("<hub name>", "<connection string with listen access>");
    var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);

    // Displays the registration ID so you know it was successful
    if (result.RegistrationId != null)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Registration successful: " + result.RegistrationId);
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }

}
```